# Redirect (react router dom) giving Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new Reactjs, I'm using fetch for api call. I want to redirect the page with api data on some other page, for that I'm using below code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';
import { Link,Redirect  } from 'react-router-dom';

fetchCatList(){
        let catID = "5c2f74e8a4d846591b2b1a41";
        // fetch("http://sfsdfsdfsdf/api/listing",{
        // method: 'POST',
        // body: JSON.stringify({
     //        category_id: catID,       
     //      }),
        // headers:{
        //  'Content-Type':'application/json',
        // },
        // })
     //      .then(res => res.json())
     //      .then(json => this.setState({catlist:json.data}));  

          fetch("http://sdfsdfsdf/api/listing", {
              method: "post",
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },

              //make sure to serialize your JSON body
              body: JSON.stringify({
                category_id: catID,             
              })
            })
            .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
            .then(function(response){ 
               //do something awesome that makes the world a better place              
               console.log(response);
               <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: '/listing_page',
                    state: { listData: response }
                 }}/>
            });


    }
```

I'm using `Redirect` from `react-router-dom` but getting below error after calling api

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression 
>   no-unused-expressions
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to to use redirect with return.

```
render () {
  if(this.state.toListing) {
    return <Redirect push to="/listing_page" />
  }
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here they have mentioned that this is an eslint error and not an error from the router.

refer : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4718